# Replace newline only at the end of string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, newline

I need something like `TRIM` function to remove new line character in left or right of string.

I can not use the below code:

```
DECLARE @str nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World' + CHAR(10)
SET @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Str, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
```

because I have new line in middle of the variable. I need to remove only the new line character in position of start or end.

I was expected the `TRIM` function do this but I failed.
Do you know any other function?

Answer (score 0):

If the newline is always the last character then:

```
DECLARE @str nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World' + CHAR(10)
SELECT  substring(@str,1,len(@str)-1)
```

if its the last occurrence of the string you want then:

```
SELECT REVERSE(Reverse(Stuff(@str, CharIndex(CHAR(10),@str),1,'')))
```

Answer (score 0):

One method you can use is,

```
DECLARE @str nVarchar(MAX) =  CHAR(10) +'Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World' + CHAR(10)

SELECT      (CASE WHEN LEFT(@str,1)  = CHAR(10) THEN '' ELSE LEFT(@str,1) END)  
        +   SUBSTRING(@str,2,LEN(@str)-2)
        +   (CASE WHEN RIGHT(@str,1)  = CHAR(10) THEN '' ELSE RIGHT(@str,1) END)
```

Get the first letter if it is not `CHAR(10)`
+ get the subs tring from second to second last letters + get the last letter if it is not `CHAR(10)`.

You can create this as an user defined function.

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [String Utility Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119(v=sql.110).aspx) provided by Microsoft and you will get regular expression support directly in your T-SQL statements.

[image]

This might look such a huge effort (implementing SQL CLR functions) for soloving such a simple task, but trust me, having these functions will simplify your solutions in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `TRIM(char(10) FROM @string)`

```
Declare @string varchar(50) = 'Remove new line' +char(10) + 'only from end of the string.' + char(10) + char(10) + char(10) + char(10)

print  TRIM(char(10) FROM @string) + ' the end!'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**